# Convert string to another string over a smaller alphabet, and vice versa.

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

I'm trying to find the most suitable algorithm to convert a string $\alpha$ over the alphabet $\Sigma$ of size $| \Sigma | = n$ to string $\beta$ over the alphabet $\Omega$ of size $| \Omega | = n-1$, and vice versa. By suitable I mean the balance of algorithm speed, implementation complexity, and overhead of the string length $| \beta | - | \alpha |$.

I've found several algorithms, but maybe there is some unknown to me. Perhaps you know such algorithms. Here's what I found:

1. Conventional byte (character) stuffing. Pretty simple, but worst-case overhead is 200%.
2. [Consistent overhead byte stuffing (COBS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_Overhead_Byte_Stuffing). Also quite easy to implement. Worst-case overhead is much better than conventional byte stuffing.
3. Think of the input string as a long number of base $n$, convert this number to base $n-1$. Very complex and computational heavy as compared with previous methods, but worst-case overhead is better if I'm not mistaken.

Anything else?

Comment: Are you wanting the composition of the two conversions to be an identity? So $g(f(\alpha))=\alpha$ and $f(g(\beta))=\beta$? Or just want two maps?

Comment: @alex.jordan Yes, so that I can apply the inverse transform and get the original string. I don't know whether there are any other mapping methods in addition to described above (I think should be), but if they are, it would be good to know about them.

Comment: Some thoughts: It's true that COBS worst-case overhead is much better than conventional byte stuffing, but for random data the average overhead is similar, and the later is much simpler (no buffering). In practice you ofter know that, either the data is uniformly random, or you know that some bytes have low probability. Lacking knowledge, and to minimize the probability of worst-case scenario, you could even change the escape character by some predefined schedule.

Comment: @leonbloy Yeap, that's why I don't like COBS - because it requires buffering. But conventional stuffing has some disadvantages if you use it in embedded devices (not critical, but unpleasant). The best algorithm for me would be something between: with overhead near COBS and without buffering. Unfortunately I don't know whether it exists or not.

Comment: I'm curious aboute those disadvantages ...

Comment: @leonbloy All these algorithms are needed for network communication (message framing). Embedded networks typically have relatively small bandwidth. So, 200% potential overhead is undesirable. The second issue is related to the implementation details. We can encode and decode messages on the fly in the interrupt service routine (e.g. UART), but sometimes you need to make isr as short as possible. Inability to encode/decode messages on the fly leads to necessity of 200% buffer size to store encoded message. Sometimes this is a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this counts, but it's an idea you might be interested in. In real world applications, you can identify a string in the $\Omega$ alphabet that would never ever ever arise in a real message. Neither in the $\Omega$ alphabet, nor in the $\Sigma$ alphabet after the simple embedding from $\Omega$ to $\Sigma$. Then you can use that string to represent one letter from $\Sigma$.

Let's say $\omega$ is such a string, something like "fhqwhgads" in English, although you could get away with something shorter. For notation, let $$\Sigma=\{s_0,s_1,\ldots, s_{n-1}\}\qquad\Omega=\{w_1,w_2,\ldots,w_{n-1}\}$$

Then map $$\DeclareMathOperator{\strings}{strings}f:\strings(\Sigma)\to\strings(\Omega)\quad f(s_i)=w_i\text{ when }i>0\quad f(s_0)=\omega$$ The inverse map would first examine a string $\beta$ for instances of $\omega$ and convert them to $s_0$, and then convert remaining $w_i$ to $s_i$. This relies on you knowing that $\omega$ would never practically arise in a real message from either alphabet.

Comment: This is similar to the conventional character stuffing, but you words about the string that would never arise in a real message gave me some food for thought. I must think things over. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not what you are looking into (this a math site, not a programming site), but anyway: a simple conventional byte stuffing algorithm with some input shifting (each time we need to "escape", we change the offset, so as to miminize the probability of worst-case scenarios). Overhead (average) should be below 1%. Tested.

Encoder:

```
/********************  encode. c **************************/
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 255                   //restricted alphabet 
#define NP1 (N+1)

#define DISALLOWED_CHAR 0 // only restrction: these three must be different 
#define ESCAPE_CHAR     1
#define ESCAPE_CHAR2    2

#define STEP            7 // any number, preferably coprime with NP1

int offset = 0;

void txraw(int c) {
    putchar(c);
}

void tx(int c) {
    c = (c + offset) % NP1;
    if (c == DISALLOWED_CHAR || c == ESCAPE_CHAR) {
    txraw(ESCAPE_CHAR);
    txraw(c == ESCAPE_CHAR ? ESCAPE_CHAR : ESCAPE_CHAR2);
    offset = (offset + STEP) % NP1;
    } else {
    txraw(c);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) >= 0) {
    tx(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Decoder:

```
/********************  decode. c **************************/
#include<stdio.h>

#define N 255                   //restricted alphabet 
#define NP1 (N+1)

#define DISALLOWED_CHAR 0 // only restrction: these must be different 
#define ESCAPE_CHAR     1
#define ESCAPE_CHAR2    2

#define STEP            7

int offset = 0;
int pendingEsc = 0;

int decode(int c) { // -2 if more to read
    int oo = offset;
    if (pendingEsc) {
        c = c  != ESCAPE_CHAR ? DISALLOWED_CHAR : ESCAPE_CHAR;
        pendingEsc = 0;
        offset = (offset + STEP) % NP1;
    } else {
        if (c == ESCAPE_CHAR) {
            pendingEsc = 1;
            return -2;
        }
    }
    return (c - oo) % NP1;
}

int readx() { // -2 if more to read
    int c = getchar();
    if (c == -1)       return c;
    else        return decode(c);
}

int main(void) { // decodes stdin -> stdout
    int c;
    while (1) {
        c = readx();
        if (c >= 0)
            putchar(c);
        else if (c == -1)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're wrong. Maybe this is not a magic fancy-pancy mathematical algorithm (of which I dreamed) that solves all the problems, but I like this idea. It helps to deal with the situation when the message payload includes a large number of special characters that we have to escape.